# DocuSign Edit MSI

Tags: docusignapi

Hi DocuSign CLM geeks and the DocuSign API in-house team-

Our team will be using DocuSign CLM with the DocuSign Edit add-on to easily open Microsoft Word files and save back to CLM.

We'd like to include the installation of DocuSign Edit in our Silent Mode installation configuration. **We're hoping there's an msi File available for the DocuSign Edit extension?**  If so, please link!

Plan B- If we were to make our own msi from the available exe, does anyone have a trail stomped out for doing this? (a blog post, documentation, step by step, video demo, even a horror story)

Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 0):

https://tools.springcm.com/sites/default/files/apps/docusign-edit-pc-2.01.00.exe

This is an exe that is built from an MSI, so it is an MSI.

If you want to get the MSI out of this https://www.codetwo.com/kb/msi-from-exe/:

The first method is based on the fact that most installers extract their .msi files to the temporary files folder during the installation process. To extract an MSI file from an EXE installer, you need to:

Launch your .exe file.
When you see the first prompt (e.g. a question about whether you want to continue installation, accept a license agreement, etc.), do not click anything in this window and do not close it.
Open Windows Explorer, type %temp% in the address bar and press Enter.
Sort the files in the folder by the modification date. The newest file on the list should be the .msi file you are looking for.
Copy the MSI file to a safe location before you close the installer prompt window (see step 2). Be aware that if you close the installer window, the MSI file will be immediately deleted from the temporary files folder.
The second method uses a free third-party tool called 7-Zip to browse the content of the .exe installer file. Follow the steps below.

Download 7-Zip from this page and install it.
Right-click on the .exe file (from which you want to extract an .msi file) and from the shortcut menu choose 7-Zip > Open Archive.
Do not extract any files yet. Instead, browse and look for the folder MSI within the contents. It might take some time to find this folder because it is not always located directly in the root directory (its location may vary depending on the installer).
When you locate the MSI folder, you will notice that it most likely does not contain any .msi files, but a file or files with no extensions and rather cryptic names such as 132. Despite these misleading names, these are actually the MSI files you are looking for.
Drag and drop these files to any desired folder or select them and extract them with 7-Zip. Close 7-Zip after that.
Change the names of the extracted files so that they include the .msi extension.
If there are two files, the larger one is the 64-bit installer, and the smaller one is the 32-bit version. Use the one you need.

Finally, if you want to tweak an MSI, you can use the Orca tool by Microsoft - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/orca-exe